# mongodb(mongoose) how to show ranking of tags

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design, mongodb-query, database-schema

Say I have a schema like this,

**Books.js**

```
const books = new Schema({
    _user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    title: String,
    language: String,
    description: String,   
    tags: {type: Object, ref: 'Tags'},

})
```

**Tags.js**

```
const tag = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
})
```

I would like to show the ranking of tags currently stored in book collection with the total count.
For example if I have the following data

**Data 1**

```
  title: momo,
    language: korean,
    description: a korean book
    tags: [{name: adventure, description: genre of fiction in which an adventure, an exciting undertaking involving risk and physical danger, forms the main storyline}, 
{name: children, description: blahblah},  {name: short, description: blahblahblah}]
```

**Data 2**

```
  title: tarzarn,
    language: english,
    description: english book
    tags: [{name: adventure, description: genre of fiction in which an adventure, an exciting undertaking involving risk and physical danger, forms the main storyline}, 
{name: children, description: blahblah},  {name: long, description: blahblahblah}]
```

**Data 3
**

```
  title: Am I small,
    language: Korean,
    description: korean book
    tags: [{name: adventure, description: genre of fiction in which an adventure, an exciting undertaking involving risk and physical danger, forms the main storyline}, 
{name: children, description: blahblah}]
```

Here we can see tags with *adventure* appears 3 times , *children* 2 times, *short* 1 time and *long* 1 time

Hence the ranking of the tags should be

1. Adventure : 3
2. Children : 2
3. Short : 1
4. long: 1

How would i be able to achieve this through mongodb query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **MongoDB aggregation** pipeline stages `$unwind and then $group`

```
db.books.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$tags.name",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can find the working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YOl-QqwJz2j)